# Android, Java: Bitmap.eraseColor deleting the entire graphic

Tags: java, android

I'm learning how to make apps for android starting with trivial tasks such as drawing a graphic on the screen, but when I remove the background color (white) it just removes the entire graphic and makes it completely white.

My code is:

```
public Sprite(int xx, int yy, InputStream is, boolean d){
        x = xx;
        y = yy;
        Bitmap old = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        b = old.copy(old.getConfig(), true);
        b.eraseColor(Color.WHITE);
        draw = d;
        old.recycle();
        RenderView.addSprite(this);
    }
```

Where I draw the images the code is:

```
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        canvas.drawRGB(0,0,0);
        for (Sprite spr : sprites){
            if (spr.getDraw()){
                canvas.drawBitmap(spr.getBitmap(), spr.getX(), spr.getY(), null);
            }
        }
        invalidate();
    }
```

[image: this is the debug graphic I'm using]

All i see on my android is a black screen as intended and a white box (my problem)

Am I missing something? or did something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to draw a bitmap which has alpha, you need to use a paint with alpha:

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setAlpha(100);
canvas.drawBitmap(spr.getBitmap(), spr.getX(), spr.getY(), paint);
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Well at least it shows gray now, but still it doesn't work as expected :/

Comment: what does that mean? what's happening now?

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#eraseColor(int)

> public void eraseColor (int c) Fills the bitmap's pixels with the
>   specified Color.

Use Bitmap.setPixels or Bitmap.setPixel to replace the color of a pixel.  And yes, this means you'll have to write a method that iterates through every pixel or block of pixels on the bitmap and check if it is you want to replace with WHITE.

Comment: What a strange method name then.

Thanks.